# Building online store

Tags: e-commerce, online-store

Many online store share common features, such as payment handling, order tracking, recommendation, shopping cart, CMS, etc.

Are there common opensource / commercial frameworks or packages that developers are using to build these site? Or do many of them building it from scratch?

Services like Shopify look simple to use but I don't want my site to look too right out of a Can and I am worry that there might be limit to the customization I can do.

Can someone point me to a right direction as to what technologies are available? I am looking for a solution that is not restrictive and has plenty of support from the community.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of open source solutions out in the wild.

If I were to build an e-shop I would  probably take a closer look at Satchmo. Now I'm biased as I like python and postgresql. The system is based on Django, which has a very flexible templating system. But of course it is up to you to make the design.

Check out the features available and the store gallery to see if this is something for you.
http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/features.html

// John

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the info.
Is it a solution that will allow me to start small and build to something extensive when I need to...?
Some solutions out there are simple but limited and others are so huge that I'll get lost and don't know where to start.
I have some experience in setting up and running a Drupal site, does it help with Satchmo?

I suppose I have to get my hands dirty to find out, but I want to limit the number of platform I have try.
Thanks again.

Comment: If you are used to Drupal and PHP then perhaps you should stick with that. Then check out www.ubercart.org which integrates into Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

here's a [blog post](http://www.solidshops.com/blog/ecommerce/is-solidshops-a-good-alternative-to-magento-oscommerce-ubercart-and-other-open-source-packages/) I've written about comparing open source ecommerce packages with hosted ones.

We've built [SolidShops.com](http://www.solidshops.com) as a hosted ecommerce solution which allows you to build 100% custom and unique stores in html/css.

In the end, it all depends on whether you have budget to go with a hosted solution or if you are willing to install, update, configure, secure, ... an open source package like magento.

Answer (score 1):

[oscommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/) is vastly used also.
You can also buy a ready-made template for it on template selling websites like [template monster](http://www.templatemonster.com/).

So for about $200 you can have your whole design/coding done. That is, unles you want custom stuff.

Comment: I would say oscommerce is the easiest way to start. Especially if we have a hosting with CPanel since it provided with free install.